# how to install RedisJson on macbook M1?

Tags: redis, apple-silicon

I tried redisJson version v1.0.4 and use the rejson.so file, but it's not a mach-o file.

How to install RedisJson on Macbook M1? Are there any methods to make the code (apart from using docker...) Thank you

Comment: Did you try RedisJSON 2.x?

Comment: just solve it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just solve the problem and install redisjson on my mbp M1.

1. git clone the repo, use 2.x version (I used v2.0.8).
2. cd into the repo && make
3. If you meet errors like:

```
make setup deps/readies/mk/main:6: *** GNU Make version is too old. Aborting. stop.
```

go to `https://www.gnu.org/software/make/` to download the latest verison (I remember it is around year 2020) use `tar -zxvf` to unzip it

4. cd into `RedisJson/`, use `/path/to/make-4.3/make`
5. You will find a rejson.so file under bin/macos-x64-release, copy
   that into `/usr/local/bin`
6. in redis.conf, add the line loadmodule '/usr/local/bin/rejson.so'
7. `redis-server redis.conf` it should work (check the log file)

It takes some time to figure out this. Thanks to some blogs [update make](http://www.myjoyoo.com/page/2)
and [get rejson.so](https://bestlifeforzhi.medium.com/redisjson-mac-os-m1-98b390984e3b)